# Would it be energy efficient for phones to include actual GPS chip?

Tags: gps, efficiency, android, iphone, modem

None of the smartphones today have dedicated GPS chips in them, they only have a GPS capability that stems from byproduct features of the modem chips. Because of that, the GPS capability is very limited and poor, for example, you only receive one basic L1 signal, whereas if there was a GPS chip — it would also receive L2E as differential signal, or SBAS - a correction signal, thus drastically improving accuracy.

Question is would they ever do it, or would it be too big of a hit on the battery, some of the chips require pretty high voltage for some reason like 3V.

Comment: *byproduct features of the modem chips* - huh?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Phone modem has super basic GPS feature added to it, no dedicated GPS chips

Comment: They have a dedicated chip such as [BCM47755](https://www.broadcom.com/products/wireless/gnss-gps-socs/bcm47755)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Source. Because I guarantee you that chip does not exist in iPhone.

Comment: iPhone is not the only smartphone around. https://www.gsa.europa.eu/newsroom/news/world-s-first-dual-frequency-gnss-smartphone-hits-market

Comment: @EugeneSh. Alright I know about this, one phone out of thousands isn’t proof of anything. Besides it needs to be 10Hz to be useful for anything other than walking anyway. Also it is not a differential chip, it doesn’t listen to SBAS, so it is as useless as the imbedded GPS that is in every phone.

Comment: This is using a dedicated chip, which you claim it doesn't. As for iPhone, it is using one from the same family - BCM47734 as you can see [here](http://www.techinsights.com/about-techinsights/overview/blog/apple-iphone-7-teardown/).

Comment: The question isn't really how much power it uses (because you'd shut it off when not being used) but whether the added cost would drive away more customers than the added feature (slightly better GPS location) would attract.

Comment: If a GPS receiver functionality is embedded into some bigger chip (like modem) , it doesn't mean that it has less functionality than a "dedicated GPS". Every reputable LTE modem does have a GPS receiver embedded: *"Additionally, XMM 7560 includes an integrated 4 mode GNSS with GPS, Galileo, GLONASS, and BeiDou positioning systems for worldwide satellite navigation support."*, see https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/wireless-products/mobile-communications/xmm-7560-brief.html

Comment: I think you mean L2C instead of “L2E”. Or even L2P, although a phone would not likely have semi-codeless tracking.

Answer (score 11):

> None of the smartphones today have dedicated GPS chips in them, they only have a GPS capability that stems from byproduct features of the modem chips.

That's not true. GPS functionality in phones is done either with a dedicated chip, or with a dedicated GPS receiver within a System-On-Chip (which is effectively the same as having a dedicated chip).

> Because of that, the GPS capability is very limited and poor

Huh, that would be news to me. In fact, I find GPS performance of phones astonishing, especially considering the fact that you can't just reserve the same size of antenna as in e.g. nautic navigation systems.

> you only receive one basic L1 signal, whereas if there was a GPS chip — it would also receive L2E as differential signal, or SBAS - a correction signal, thus drastically improving accuracy.

As far as I can see, embedded GPS chips basically support all features of civilian GPS. Your claim has no backing.

My phone's GPS functionality has excellent differential GPS capabilities, for example.

> Question is would they ever do it, or would it be too big of a hit on the battery, some of the chips require pretty high voltage for some reason like 3V.

Since they do, the answer is clear: Using the GPS circuitry / antenna does cost some battery, but every phone has GPS and thus it does work.

3V isn't per se a high voltage, even inside a smart phone – it's significantly below battery voltage, so easy and low-loss generatable from the battery.

Comment: It really is amazing that GPS receivers can pick up signals lower than 140dBm

Comment: That, too, but that's just the beauty of high spreading factors/high processing gain in general :)